# How to configure multilingual where language option resides in request url sitecore webpage

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

i have some queries regarding sitecore multilingual and seeking your help.could you please read the query below: i am aware about the item language version,site definition configuration on different url for different country. However,the requirement is quite different i.e same url for all country,but the content should display on language of respective country ,where language will reside on url .Ex : www.mysite.com/en and www.mysite.com/ja .Do you have any hints and share some of the reference with me please ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a `languageEmbedding="always" languageLocation="filePath"` in your Link Provider definition in web.config.

```xml
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add 
        name="sitecore"
        type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"
        languageEmbedding="always"
        languageLocation="filePath" 
        ... />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

Your urls will always include language part as the first segment, e.g.:

```
www.mysite.com/en/about-us
www.mysite.com/ja/about-us
```

You can change the language by setting:

```cs
Sitecore.Context.SetLanguage(LanguageManager.GetLanguage("ja"), false);
```

Comment: Hi Marek,Well! ,i hope you are well!,and thanks for your unconditional help/support.Happy Christmas in advance .I knew about above configurations .my requirment is,in ui,we are having the options for user to switch more than one language option on click. like japanese,english,french etc.However the default language will be the respective country,from where the request came from. and the url will change as above you mentioned at last after clicking language option every time.how can we do that!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Add some images/scenarios to your question. What exactly you want to achieve and what is the issue?

Comment: Thanks Marek! i will add some screen/pic shortly.

Comment: Hi Marek! as you asked for more specific/clear question.we need multilingual site configuration for Single domain!Hope,this clarifies more then previous question

Comment: Sitecore has this out of the box. You don't have to configure anything. You just add chosen languages and optionally you can set whether language info should be in url, param or cookie. That's it.